# Apple: Compile clang frame size with -O0 vs -O2 (kernel)

Tags: c, macos, kernel, clang, kernel-extension

I have an existing project, which we compile DEBUG for developers (and -O0 so lldb makes sense). But I have one function in particular that balloons in size when -O0 is used:

```
-O2 -Wframe-larger-than=100
warning: stack frame size of 168 bytes in function 'dsl_scan_visitbp'
```

```
-O0 -Wframe-larger-than=100
warning: stack frame size of 1160 bytes in function 'dsl_scan_visitbp'
```

and with some recursion, the stack can be very trashed (16K stacks in kernel).

First thing to inspect are any local variables, but I believe there are only two:

```
        dsl_pool_t *dp = scn->scn_dp;
        blkptr_t *bp_toread = NULL;
```

If you want to see the whole function: 
https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/blob/master/module/zfs/dsl_scan.c#L1908
(Linux sources, but dealing with Apple clang port)

There are a bunch of `alwaysinline` in that sourcefile, which may also come to play here.

But I am curious why it grows so large with -O0?

Then what to do about it, I can't see any Apple-clang #pragmas to turn "on" optimize in a source file (only turning off optimize) for one function, or one file. If I knew what the cause was, perhaps I can control that specific issue with a different pragma.

Only solution I see right now, is to have `dsl_scan.c` processed differently in the Makefile, so that only that file always gets -O2. But that is a bit tedious.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out increasing amounts of the function, starting at the end, to work out which line is causing it to blow up? Please update your question with the minimum code that causes the function's frame to blow up here, including a note along the lines of "if I comment out XYZ" it stays small. It may also be helpful to post the generated assembly code, as actually building the code in question ourselves in the same way you are is going to be rather difficult.

Comment: Yeah I could work on that.. I was expecting there was an ".o inspection tool" that would dump the frame and just tell me what engorges :)

Comment: `warning: stack frame size of 120 bytes in function 'dsl_scan_visitbp'`
Line commented out:

//  if (dsl_scan_recurse(scn, ds, ostype, dnp, bp_toread, zb, tx) != 0)

Comment: Pushes the problem up a function. However, I noticed that if I take out "always_inline" during DEBUG builds, it shrinks down to some 600 bytes, which might just be enough.

Comment: Yes, I think your problem is caused by the `always_inline` attributes. I've added an answer that explains what I think is going on. (As it's a bit long for a comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the code base, so I don't see any obvious variables that would be taking large amounts of stack space. However, I notice that the functions (including the `always_inline`d) are quite long. Typically, in debug builds, *every* variable and temporary expression result is assigned a *unique* space in the stack frame, regardless of scope. So even if 2 variables' lifetimes do not overlap (e.g. one is declared in the `if` block, and another in the `else` block) they will be allocated separate spaces in memory. So this can add up even if there are a lot of small short-lived variables and temporary values.

You are probably best off disabling `always_inline` attributes in all functions called by this function in debug builds, as this avoids pre-allocating memory for all possible branches of execution even if they are never taken, or if they are declared in a function that's not involved in the recursion.

Comment: In the end, it turned out to be quite straight forward to have the Makefile flip -O2 on, using:    zfs-dsl_scan.$(OBJEXT): CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS:-O0%=-O2)